# xlwings - automation error while inserting a value in a new sheet

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

on windows 10
python 3.6.5
xlwings 0.24.9

```
@xw.func 
@xw.arg('x'), np.array)
@xw.arg('y'), np.array) 
def double_sum(x, y):
        """Returns twice the sum of the two arguments"""
        wb = xw.Book().caller()
        val = np.random.randint(10) * (x + y)
        #wb.sheets[0].range('E3').value = val
        sh = wb.sheets.add('new sheet')
        sh.range('A2').value = val
        return val
```

Results:

- it does not create the new sheet (nor a new book)
- inserting a value into that new sheet (or even in the existing sheet using the commented `wb.sheets[0].range('E3').value = val`) returns a: "Automation error" in the spreadsheet

on the console:

```
AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 482, in __setattr__
    self._oleobj_.Invoke(*(args + (value,) + defArgs)) pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)
```

Any lead as what maybe causing the trouble please?
Thanks

Comment: Generally speaking, UDFs can only return values, they cannot manipulate the Excel object API, see also: https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/645